# how to compare two dictionaries with different keys but similar values and delete the duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, key

I am quite new to python and I am keen on learning. I have two dictionaries that have different keys but similar values in it, as follows:

```
dict_a = {'r1': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8'], 'r2': ['c9', 'c10', 'c11'], 'r3': ['c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15']}
```

```
dict_b = {'f1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15']}
```

Is it possible to compare both dictionaries and delete the duplicate values in it? I would like to obtain the following dictionaries at the end:

```
dict_a_new = {'r1': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8'], 'r2': ['c9', 'c10', 'c11'], 'r3': ['c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15']}
```

```
dict_b_new = {'f1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'}
```

I have tried the following syntax, but it doesn't work for me.

```
dict_b_new = {k: dict_b[k] for k in set(dict_b) - set(dict_a)}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `dict_a_new` seems unchanged? Are there any cases where `dict_a_new` would be different? Do you merely want to eliminate all elements from the values in `dict_b` that already appear in some value of `dict_a` to generate `dict_b_new`?

Comment: Also, can there be duplicate values in any of the lists? And should those duplicates be removed, leaving only a single value, or should any duplicates remain? (e.g. `dict_a = ['x': ['a', 'b', 'a']; dict_b = ['x': ['b']]`)

Comment: There can be duplicates in dict_a but I would like to keep it unchanged. I need to remove all the duplicate values from dict_b as they are repetitive for the application I am using them for. The key for both dictionaries are different. for example dict_a, keys are r1, r2, r3 and for dict_b is f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set with all the items in `dict_a`, and then create `dict_b_new` with all the items in dict_b that are not in the set:

```
set_a = {item for lst in dict_a.values() for item in lst}
dict_b_new = {k: [item for item in lst if item not in set_a] for k, lst in dict_b.items()}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PuzzledAgreeableProspect

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `dict_a` has multiple keys, not only `r1`, `r2`, `r3`, and `dict_b` has a single key.

```py
from itertools import chain

difference = set(*dict_b.values()) - set(chain(*dict_a.values()))
# {'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'}

dict_b_new = {k: difference for k in dict_b.keys()}
```

`itertools.chain` concatenate iterables.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain